# Replace <td> content in a <table> without changing or having fixed height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the  element the same size AND alternate text within the element.  The text and alternate text can be any length.  I currently truncate the alternate text by guessing at the length the text will be in the  element (but don't account for the original text possibly having multiple rows).  It sorta works ok if everything is a single line and the user doesn't resize the window.  `$(window).resize(findCELLSIZE);` fires too often (everytime I replace the element), so I'm not using that to recalculate the width and height.

I have HTML (simlified) as:

```
<table id='main'>
   <thead>
     <th width='100'>first</th>
     <th>second</th>
     <th width='100'>third</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Blah</td>
       <td class='special' data-text="<span class='highlight'>different BLAH1</span>,.,<span class='highlight2'>short BLAH2</span>">Blah Blah</td>
       <td>Blah</td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

with simplified jQuery/javascript as:

```
var DESCRIPTIONheight = [];
var DESCRIPTIONwidth = 0;
function findCELLSIZE () {
   $("#main tbody tr").each(function() { 
       var thatwidth = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').width();
       if (thatwidth >= DESCRIPTIONwidth) { DESCRIPTIONwidth = thatwidth+1; }
   });
   $(".special").each(function () {
       $(this).closest('tr').height('');
       DESCRIPTIONheight.push($(this).height()+1);
   });
}
findCELLSIZE();
//$(window).resize(findCELLSIZE);
function flashEXPRESS() {
    $(".special").each(function (index) {
      var next = $(this).data('text').split(/,\.,/)[0];
      var temp = '';
      if (next != $(this).data('text')) {
         temp = $(this).data('text').split(/^(.+?),\.,/)[0] +',.,';
      }
      temp = temp + $(this).html();
      var mytextlength = next.match(/>(.*?)<\/span>$/i);
      if(mytextlength) {
         if (mytextlength[1].length*7 > DESCRIPTIONwidth) { 
           mytextlength[1] = mytextlength[1].substring(0,Math.floor(DESCRIPTIONwidth/7));
           next = next.replace(/>(.*?)<\/span>$/i,'>'+mytextlength[1]+'</span>');
         }
      }
      $(this).html(next);
      $(this).width(DESCRIPTIONwidth);
      $(this).data('text', temp);
      $(this).closest('tr').height(DESCRIPTIONheight[index]);
   });
}
var flashEXPRESSid = 0;
flashEXPRESSid = setInterval(flashEXPRESS,1000);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBkrc/9/) My code runs in IE8, but not Firefox 15 (there must be an issue with jQuery writting html5 data attributes)

Comment: I have read this question three times, and am still not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to alternate content within the <td> element without changing the original size of the <td> element.  I store the alternate content in a data-text attribute delimited by ',.,'.  My current solution is flaky..

Comment: Yes. Why are you storing the alternate text in a data attribute? Can you not store it in javascript somewhere? what do you mean by not changing the original size of the td? can you not accomplish this with some simple css?

Comment: The table is large, dynamic, and currently displays as desired.   This particular <td> element expands to the limits of the window.  How would storing the data in a different manor help?  I don't see a solution with CSS.  Unless there is CSS that doesn't allow the table to change dimensionally after rendered, or there is a way to make a <td> element just cut off the extra text (like Excel does when there is to much text in a cell).

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VzA73/

Comment: having a delimited string which also contains html in a data attribute just seems like it should not be necessary is all. maybe even just the `different` and `short` text could be held in two separate data attributes, and the class could be added dynamically using code. who knows... just seems off.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6scZw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the CSS suggestions worked completely (the actual table is more complicated: it could be the table, IE8, or both).  The solution is to not change the  element and instead make a  element with the same size, position with a greater z-index. [Updated Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/GBkrc/14/)  To be browser neutral, I'm going to have to figure out why jQuery position and size are not normalized across different browsers...